# Meteor Js limiting access to my meteor app

Tags: meteor, iron-router, user-accounts

I have a meteor app and I want to host it, but I only want a few people to login to it and have access to it, at most 5 people. How Do I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create 5 accounts like these:

```
 Meteor.startup(function () {
   if (Meteor.users.find().count() === 0) {
     Accounts.createUser({
        username: 'xxxxx',
        email: 'xxxx@xxxx.xx',
        password: 'xxxxxxx',
        profile: {}
     });
    ...
   }
 });
```

And avoid possiblity to create new user:

```
AccountsTemplates.configure({
     forbidClientAccountCreation: true,
 });
```

Comment: What about logging them in

Comment: You have to send username and password to them and use account login page.

Comment: Can I use that startup function with materialize :user accounts? Should the startup function live in the server folder

Comment: Meteor.startup is a meteor function so you can always use it, all the code provided is server side code.

Answer (score 0):

You can block the creation of new users with:

```
Accounts.config({ forbidClientAccountCreation : true });
```

Checking the number of users in `Meteor.startup` will prevent creation of users when you restart you app and already 5 users have been created.

When 5 users have been created, you can throw an error in `Accounts.onCreateUser`. onCreateUser is called every time a new user is about to be created. Throwing the error will cancel user creation.

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
       if (Meteor.users.find().count() >= 5)
          Accounts.config({
              forbidClientAccountCreation : true
          });
  });

  Accounts.onCreateUser(function (options, user) {
     var numberOfUsers = Meteor.users.find().count();
     if (numberOfUsers >= 4) {
         Accounts.config({
             forbidClientAccountCreation : true
         });
     };
     if (numberOfUsers >= 5) 
       throw new Meteor.Error(403, "Signup forbidden");
     return user;
  });
}
```